# Recover deleted (not trashed) emails from iCloud

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, data-recovery

Incorrect rule set-up deleted a lot of emails. Not "move to Trash". Don't see them any more in the web interface, and the files appear to be gone from my hard drive.

Any chance of recovery? Either through Apple Mail or through web? Or Apple customer service?

Comment: was the rule set to move the emails/files to the trash / bin or delete? Delete often means removed ie like sending to /null.

Comment: The "Delete Message" option, not the "Move to Trash". Not swift. Won't do that again. I suspect that if recoverable, it's through the iCloud server, not my local machine.